# Расположение базы данных в настройках phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, настройки

Где в phpmyadmin указывается расположение на диске базы данных? Как узнать путь к базе данных каким-либо образом (пускай даже не в phpmyadmin)?

Comment: В phpmyadmin расположение базы на диске не указывается. Максимум - в конфигурационном файле указан ip и порт сервера mysql к которому происходит подключение. А базу на диск кладет тот mysql сервер к которому происходит подключение и работает она сама по себе, для ее работы phpmyadmin вообще не требуется

Comment: Хотя вот тут https://www.dmosk.ru/miniinstruktions.php?mini=mysql-path показано как узнать путь (`select @@datadir`). но изменять ее можно только в настройках самого mysql

Comment: @Mike подскажите как найти путь к базе данных хоть каким-нибудь образом (желательно нужна подробная инструкция).

Comment: может быть, имеет место «[ошибка молотка и микроскопа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576)»? для чего вам нужно расположение файлов, в которых сервер хранит различные части базы данных? хотите сделать резервную копию? но для этого не нужно знать, где именно находятся файлы, составляющие базу данных.

Comment: @htmllayout А какая у вас операционная система ?

Comment: Если все таки просто узнать, то выполните в phpmyadmin запрос `select @@datadir`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я буду переносить базу данных с одного компьютера на другой, поэтому хочу знать расположение базы данных.

Comment: @Mike windows 7 Home

Comment: В интернете пишут  что надо запустить `mysqld.exe --help --verbose >help.txt` (в каталоге где mysql лежит, например. соответственно там большой вывод этой команды, который окажется в help.txt, там находите строку "Default options are read from the following files in the given order" сразу после нее строка где искать конфиг файл. Там перечисляется несколько мест где он может быть. Ищете файл, находите в нем datadir. А вообще как узнать через запрос я выше писал.

Comment: А вообще может пойти прямым путем. найти в гугле "перенос mysql на другой сервер windows" там много полезных ссылок по переносу. и большинство все таки сводится в mysqldump и восстановлению этого. А то вдруг на новом компьютере версия mysql окажется чуточку другой и тогда сырые файлы БД не подойдут.

Comment: @Mike, вот зачем давать ссылку на мусорный сайт (вполне возможно — однодневку), если там прямо приведена ссылка на [оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2482234)?

Comment: @htmllayout, `я буду переносить базу данных с одного компьютера на другой` — ну вот, я угадал: вам нужен дамп базы, а не файлы, по которым база размазана. [mysql dump базы](https://www.yandex.ru/search/?text=mysql%20dump%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B). вроде это можно сделать даже с помощью свистелки под названием phpmyadmin. хотя надёжнее, конечно, воспользоваться прилагающейся к серверу программой mysqldump.